# How can I dismiss view?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller

If I add view like this: `[myView addSubview:viewController.view];` how can I dismiss it and get the old view. For example on button click

```
-(IBAction)dismiss{
//some code
}
```

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
[viewController.view removeFromSuperview];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if ([viewController.view superView])

{

      [viewController.view removeFromSuperview];

}
```

Comment: like this in my case? [self.view removeFromSuperview]