# Dismissing Presented View Controller

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad

I'm using ARC + Storyboard.

I'm not using segues, or a UINavigationController, but rather presenting each individual view with:

```
UIStoryboard *storyBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
SecondViewController *secondViewController = [storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SecondVC"];

[self presentViewController:secondViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

So, a typical flow of my App is:

MainViewController
 `presentViewController:`
SecondViewController
 `presentViewController:`
ThirdViewController
...etc

After moving forward, I don't want the previous view controller that I presented from hanging around in memory any more.

Right now, after I move on to my second view controller, I can put a break point in a timer function in MainViewController, and verify everything is still there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Note** : viewcontroller is `automatically retained` when `presentViewController:`,but in ARC it will handle retained object and will release it when appropriate .

Calling `dismissModalViewController` later on will `release the retained controller automatically`.

Answer (score 0):

Is it just me maybe I am not reading correctly? It seems there is a misunderstanding about the presented and presenting view controller?

If your MainViewController is on top and then you call:
`[mainViewController presentViewController:secondVC animated:YES completion:nil];` then secondVC becomes the presented controller and the mainViewController becomes its presentingViewController.

---

That said, it looks like you want your presenting view controller being unloaded from memory?

> "Right now, after I move on to my second view controller, I can put a break point in a timer function in MainViewController, and verify everything is still there."

If so, this is not exactly the way view controllers behave when presented like this. The `presentingViewController` will be in memory until it receives a memory warning notification and then it will unload only its view if it is not on top. (the controller object itself will be still alive).

It is not a good idea to simply release the presenting controller because it will break parent-child relationship between the controllers. You can fix this manually but it can be a bit cumbersome in some cases. Just recommended if you know what you are doing.

If you want to really kill the presentingViewController probably is better you [create an extra custom container view controller](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/BasicViewControllers/BasicViewControllers.html) so it presents view controllers and releases the former one. View controllers are not expensive, its view is what it is :)

**Note** that even if you use a navigation controller the behaviour regarding load/unload its view will be similar. Only the view is unloaded because the navigation controller retains all its view controllers.

Comment: Yes, I think you understood me correctly. I also completely understand presenting view controller and presented view controller.  I was just looking for a way to actually destroy the presenting view controller.  My application performs animations based on a timer and has multiple large data images loaded into memory. Once I change views, I don't want those those operations being fired off behind the scenes.

Comment: As a workaround I just block my timer function from being called after I present a new VC, but I'm still nervous about the large images that were loaded on each screen. I don't want negative performance impacts.

Comment: What you can do is unload all your big images manually after presenting other view controllers on top and re-load them again manually when returning.

Comment: Are you suggesting I do something like iterating through all the views and just removing them?  Something like:  for (UIView *view in self.view.subviews) { [view removeFromSuperview]; }

Comment: Just make sure you implement correctly viewDidUnload and/or viewControllerDidReceiveMemoryWarning: methods. You can write code to unload your views/data there and they will be called when memory is needed. The UIViewController handles that for you very nicely :). This is a MUST, View Controller Programming Guide for iOS http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ViewLoadingandUnloading/ViewLoadingandUnloading.html

Answer (score 0):

May be this will help.

[viewController.view removeFromSuperview];

I foud it here: [How can I dismiss view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5593438/how-can-i-dismiss-view)